# Page not redirecting after form submit

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views

I have a form which creates a new category. Previously, the form was in a different template which worked fine but since it's only a simple form I have decided to render it in modal form instead of redirecting to a different page.

The user can add a new category, however the success message and the page rendering after the form submit is not shown. It only shows up if you refresh the page. The response message is 302.

I've done similar method with other forms which worked perfectly fine.

forms.py

```py
class CategoryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_name(self):
        print(self.cleaned_data['name'])
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']

    try:
        Category.objects.get(name__iexact=name)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return name
    raise forms.ValidationError('Category Name already exists.')


class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ['name']
```

views.py

```py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CategoryView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'content/category_list.html'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    user = self.request.user
    category_list = []
    for category in categories:
        article_count = category.article_count(user)
        include = category.show or user.usertype_is_staff() or user.is_superuser
        requested_by = category.requested_by if category.requested_by else ''
        cat = {
            'reference': category.pk,
            'name': category.name,
            'show': category.show,
            'article_count': article_count,
            'has_articles': article_count > 0,
            'requested_by': requested_by,
            'requested_by_name': requested_by.profile.full_name if requested_by and requested_by.profile.full_name
            else '-'
        }
        include and category_list.append(cat)

    context['categories'] = category_list
    context['form'] = CategoryModelForm(self.request.POST or None)

    return context


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if context['form'].is_valid():
        context['form'].save()
        messages.success(request, 'Successfully created new category.')
        return redirect('content:category')
    return super(CategoryView, self).render_to_response(context)
```

category_list.html

```html
<div id="newCategory" data-id="new-account" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg"
             tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="syn-breadcrumb">
                <div class="syndicator-form-container">
                   <form class="syndicator-form" action="{% url 'content:category' %}"
                      method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="">
                        <h3 class="lighter-weight">
                            {% if user.usertype_is_supplier %}
                                Request New Category
                            {% else %}
                                Add New Category
                            {% endif %}
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-fields">
                        <div class="non-field-errors">
                            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="{{ form.name.name }}" class="d-flex flex-column fields">
                            <div class="lighter-weight"><label for="id_name">Name</label></div>
                            <div>{{ form.name }}</div>
                            <div class="field-errors">{{ form.name.errors }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submit-button">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">{% trans 'Submit' %}</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the page to be redirected to an updated list of the categories after the form submit with the success message. As well as show the error message if the category name already exists or if the fields re empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `self.request` instead of `request` even though `request` is already passed in `post` method

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = CategoryModelForm(request.POST or None)  # use request.POST
```

I would rather suggest you to use a `FormView` or rather a generic view. ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/)). You won't need to handle the form by yourself.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CategoryView(FormView):
    template_name = 'content/category_list.html'
    form = CategoryModelForm
    success_url = reverse("content:category")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.obj = form.save(commit=True)
        messages.success(self.request, 'Successfully created new category.')
        return super(CategoryView, self).form_valid(form)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        user = self.request.user
        category_list = []
        for category in categories:
            article_count = category.article_count(user)
            include = category.show or user.usertype_is_staff() or user.is_superuser
            requested_by = category.requested_by if category.requested_by else ''
            cat = {
                'reference': category.pk,
                'name': category.name,
                'show': category.show,
                'article_count': article_count,
                'has_articles': article_count > 0,
                'requested_by': requested_by,
                'requested_by_name': requested_by.profile.full_name if requested_by and requested_by.profile.full_name
                else '-'
            }
            include and category_list.append(cat)

        context['categories'] = category_list
        # form will be automatically added to context
```

Comment: first of all, my bad, context['form'] was not supposed to be there, just in the get_context_data.

second, i would like to just use TemplateView since all the categories are being displayed on the page. since it worked for my other forms, i'd like to keep the uniformity. i just wanted to know what was causing the response status 302.